Kafka consumer metric showing the age of a record
i am searching for a metric in kafka (best case would be in kafka consumer metrics) showing the age of a record.
E.g. A record was published at 2:00 am, and is consumed on 2:15am, this metric should show 15 minutes (in any representation, ns, ms, sec, etc.)
I did my research, looking for synonyms like

offset
age
latency
lag

in the confluent documentation, but nothing seems to show this kind of value.

I don't think there is consumer level metrics to see when message is consumed.Probably you can store timestamp when you receive message in consumer application.
But you can get Timestamp data stored in message written by producer or by kafka.
There are two cases.
1.You can get timestamp data set by producer while producing message to kafka.
2.you can also get timestamp data set by kafka when it received message from producer.
For case -1 you have to set this property in server.properties file
log.message.timestamp.type=CreateTime
For case -2
log.message.timestamp.type=LogAppendTime
To get Timestamp data:-
If your using kafka-console-consumer.sh use below command
->bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topicName --property print.timestamp=true
If your using own consumer application written in java use below function
->record.timestamp()
If your using own consumer application written in cpp(librdkafka) use below function
->rd_kafka_message_timestamp().
